# Copy From csv to postgres

Tags: postgresql, csv

I am having trouble using the copy from command in postgresql to import data in a csv file. I first created a table in postgresql with the following code.

```
create table sfmap (
    Address  varchar(100), 
    City varchar(50),
    State varchar(5),
    Zip varchar(6),
    County varchar(20)        
)
```

I then used the following code to copy the data in the table.

```
COPY sfmap(Address, City, State, County)
FROM 'H:\sfmap.csv'
WITH DELIMITER ','
CSV HEADER
```

Every time I do this, I get the follow error message.

`ERROR: could not open file "H:\sfmap.csv" for reading: No such file or directory
SQL state: 58P01`

I am sure the location of the file is correct. I have tried using a forward slash, two backwardslashes. I don't see what I am doing wrong.

Comment: Are you aware that the file location needs to be on the **server** where Postgres is running?

Comment: sfmap and the database are both hosted locally, so I don't think I need to use /copy.

Answer (score 0):

COPY command must be run by a Postgres superuser. Might be worth checking that.

Answer (score 0):

This is a permission issue. First, check if the file is 'read' accessible to the 'Others' group (assuming your work under Linux), and then check if the folder it is in is also 'read' accessible.